# trying to output to pdf using weasyprint fails css

Tags: css, django, pdf, weasyprint

I'm trying to output a pdf from django.  I am using weasyprint.  Here is my view:

```
def fleet_report_pdf(request):
    template = loader.get_template("Reports/fleetreport.html")
    context = {
     'crews':  models.Unit.objects.all().annotate(c=Count('memberunit__Member')),
     's31': models.Member.objects.filter(memberunit__isnull=True)
    }
    html = template.render(RequestContext(request, context))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri(), url_fetcher=request).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

The pdf loads however, the page is not styled.  when digging further, I noticed errors like these in the console:

```
Failed to load stylesheet at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/layout.css : TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable
Failed to load stylesheet at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/darkblue.css : TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable
Failed to load stylesheet at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/custom.css : TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable
```

This tells me that I'm missing something.  How to make the stylesheets callable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `request` object as a url fetcher in your `weasyprint.HTML` call (`url_fetcher=request`). You shouldn't need to provide this argument for fetching simple resources that does not require authentication or so.

See [this](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#url-fetchers) for details on URL fetchers.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That fixed the problem for the most part.  Now, All I need to do is fix some of the css coloring issues.  Thanks again.

Comment: `404 File not found` for the link above... the irony.